# Mechanism to interact timeseries database in hadoop with structured RDBMS data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, opentsdb

I am new to this Hadoop thing . What I want to accomplish is store time  series data over cloud in a distributed system. Looking at few stuffs over web OpenTSDB seems to be a feasible option for me to do so .

I also have some RDBMS databases which can be stored in distributed system   and used using hive.

What we plan to do is use timeseries databases and the structured RDBMS  data (read and write via HIVE ) and then join time series data with this   structured data . Store the output in such a way that it can be read and   write like SQL something via HIVE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're asking about Hadoop or TSDBs.

If you already had a Hadoop environment, sure, adding HBase and then OpenTSDB might make sense.

If you want alternatives that offer more query centric ideas, then Influxdb or TimescaleDb seem more popular in that realm.

If scalability is really the issue, then Cassandra with Kairos is another option.

---

As part as Hive-like processing goes, SparkSQL probably can interact with all the above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We plan to move our data on cloud and this data is a time series data. Also their are some RDBMS database so we would like to move them to cloud as well. Idea is to use both of them and if required join data between time series data and RDBMS data . So can you suggest on this ?

Comment: Again, Hadoop is not a database, nor should it really be the place wher you will be able to look it up quickly. If you are going with Amazon, for example, data in S3 is just as processable (maybe more) than HDFS... But I would say put it all in TimescaleDB (Postgres), CrateDB, or Couchbase, and see how far you get... There is no differentiating factor that says the cloud needs to run anything different than what you can install and test out locally, though, without "wasting" money on resources and storage that ultimately won't work for your business needs, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for info @cricket_007